# jQuery on completed updating a div possible?

Tags: jquery, html, callback

my jQuery code is programatically updating the contents of a div. This takes a while, since I have much content. I need an event that tells me when the div rendering is complete. Is there such a callback? Thanks.

Comment: You can call a function yourself after setting the html(_next line_), you don't need callback in this case.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the div, for instance:

```
$("selector for the div").html("the updated markup");
```

...the next line of code doesn't run until the div has been updated. At that point, the DOM updates have been completed. Normally that's good enough. If you want to be sure that those updates have been *rendered* (shown to the user), you can yield back to the browser using `setTimeout`, like this:

```
// ...do the updates...
setTimeout(function() {
    // They've almost certainly been rendered.
}, 0);
```

The delay won't be 0ms, but it'll be very brief. That gives the browser a moment to repaint (if it needs it, which varies by browser).

Comment: I think the div update is asynchronous. My jQuery code goes fast through the update line, yet the display shows the new content much later.

Comment: @user3140979: No, the update is synchronous. Again, for the *rendering*, you may have to yield back to the browser.